# Reading "bash_profile" is doing two things that are contradicting each other

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I'm very confused about how my shell is reading bash_profile.

In root, my ~/.bash_profile looks like so

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [-f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        .~/.bashrc
fi

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$HOME/sbin:$HOME/usr/sbin:$HOME/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib

export PATH=$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
unset USERNAME
```

There is no ~/.profile file.

In a user called maruhan, my ~/.bash_profile looks like so

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [-f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        .~/.bashrc
fi

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$HOME/sbin:$HOME/usr/sbin:$HOME/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/maruhan/Desktop/issac:/usr/local/lib
ASDF=$ASDF:/home

export PATH=$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export ASDF=$ASDF
unset USERNAME
```

And my ~/.profile looks like so

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/maruhan/Desktop/issac:/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
ASDF=/home:$ASDF
export ASDF=$ASDF
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

You can clearly see that ASDF is not defined in root's bash_profile.

However when I call `export`, I get this in root.

```
declare -x ASDF=":/home"
```

but nothing about LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Strangely in maruhan, running export shows both ASDF and LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Also, nothing about ASDF or LD_LIBRARY_PATH exist in /etc/environment. I also don't have a /etc/bash_profile file.

Running `echo $0` gives me `bash` for both root and maruhan.

How come LD_LIBRARY_PATH disappeared in root while ASDF is there?

Comment: How does the *root* user start `bash`? And *maruhan*?

Comment: @whjm can u help me how to check that?

Comment: `export PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH ASDF` is sufficient; you don't need to "reassign" the values. `export` marks names, not values.

Comment: @chepner I know. I wasn't 100% sure, and things weren't working out as intended, so I put it there just in case.

Comment: @CuriousKimchi -- Updated my answer.

Comment: @whjm They both seem to be interactive shells. I'll put the detail on my post

Answer (score 1):

The rules are a bit complicated. According to bash's man page:

> **INVOCATION**
>
> A **login shell** is one whose first character of argument  zero  is  a  `-`,  or  one
>   started with the `--login` option.
>
> An  **interactive  shell** is one started without non-option arguments (unless `-s` is
>   specified) and without the `-c` option whose standard input  and  error  are  both
>   connected  to terminals (as determined by `isatty(3)`), or one started with the `-i`
>   option.  `PS1` is set and `$-` includes `i` if bash is interactive, allowing  a  shell
>   script or a startup file to test this state.
>   ... ...
>   **When bash is invoked as an interactive login  shell**,  or  as  a  non-interactive
>   shell  with  the  `--login`  option, it first reads and executes commands from the
>   file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists.  After reading that file, it  looks  for
>   `~/.bash_profile`,  `~/.bash_login`,  and  `~/.profile`,  in that order, and reads and
>   executes commands from **the first one** that exists and is readable.  The  `--noprofile`
>   option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
>   ... ...
>   **When  an  interactive shell that is not a login shell is started**, bash reads and
>   executes commands from `~/.bashrc`, if that file exists.  This may be inhibited by
>   using  the  `--norc` option.  The `--rcfile` file option will force bash to read and
>   execute commands from file instead of `~/.bashrc`.
>   ... ...

Note that on some systems bash may be customized so that it would also execute a system wide rc file (e.g. `/etc/bash.bashrc`) before sourcing `~/.bashrc` for an *interactive shell* that's not a *login shell*.

Shells started by a login mechanism (usually with a *username*/*password* prompt, like console login, `telnet`, `ssh`, ...) are usually login shells. For a login shell, `$0` is usually `-bash`.

```
[local] % ssh user@host  <-- The user is trying to login
Password: P@ssw0rd
[remote] % echo $0
-bash                    <-- This is a login shell
[remote] % bash          <-- This is not a login (no username/password)
[remote] % echo $0
bash                     <-- Not a login shell
[remote] %
```

To make life easier I would put all rc things in `~/.bashrc` and *source* `~/.bashrc` in `~/.bash_profile`. For example:

```
% cat ~/.bash_profile
[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && source ~/.bashrc
% cat ~/.bashrc
# return immediately if not in an interactive shell
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return 0

export FOO=bar
PATH=$PATH:/my/path
%
```